# Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure exit Code 127

Tags: ios, automation, appium

I am getting this error when trying to run iOS appium test.  Seems I cant find much on exit code 127 failure.  Any help would be great.  Thanks

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: Command '/bin/bash /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-webdriveragent/Scripts/carthage-wrapper.sh bootstrap --platform iOS,tvOS' exited with code 127
> Build info: version: '3.6.0', revision: '6fbf3ec767', time: '2017-09-27T15:28:36.4Z'
> System info: host: 'andriidd.local', ip: '192.168.29.55', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.4', java.version: '14.0.2'
> Driver info: driver.version: IOSDriver
> remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: Command '/bin/bash /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-webdriveragent/Scripts/carthage-wrapper.sh bootstrap --platform iOS,tvOS' exited with code 127
> at getResponseForW3CError (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/errors.js:804:9)
> at asyncHandler (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/protocol.js:381:37)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$new$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:57)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$2(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:104)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:123)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
> at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:127)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:502)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:488)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:150)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:543)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:73)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:138)
> at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:89)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
> at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
> at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
> at io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver.execute(IOSDriver.java:1)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:219)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:142)
> at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:38)
> at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:83)
> at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:93)
> at io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver.(IOSDriver.java:78)
> at AppTest.setupAppium(AppTest.java:36)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
> at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
> at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:59)
> at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:458)
> at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:222)
> at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:142)
> at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:401)
> at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
> at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
> at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
> at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
> at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
> at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
> at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
> at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
> at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
> at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be related to not using the latest cartage version, try running:

`brew upgrade carthage`

Then re-run the failing command directly in terminal:

```
cd /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-webdriveragent/Scripts/
carthage-wrapper.sh bootstrap --platform iOS\,tvOS
```

You can also check this [issue](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/14703) as a reference.